# How to take a snapshot of associated data while creating a record in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

In my rails application, the DB structure is such that there are some master tables and there are some tables whose data is based on those master tables( through associations ). For example, let us consider three master tables items, brands, uoms(unit of measurement). Each of these three tables has a an attribute called "name" along with other attributes. Now we have another table called purchases. To create a purchase I need to select one item, one brand and one uom. But the problem here is if someone changes the name of the item, or any other associated data, the record in the purchase table changes.

My question is what could be the possible ways of handling this situation. One easy solution is to prevent editing of master data. But I also want to know if  one can copy the associated data in an effective way while making a purchase.

Answer (score 0):

See [Rails Active Record callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html). Callbacks allow you to write methods that will run on a specified action.

For example, see this sample code taken from the Rails documentation where the developer is modifying the data before and after running Rails model validations.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :normalize_name, on: :create
 
  # :on takes an array as well
  after_validation :set_location, on: [ :create, :update ]
 
  private
    def normalize_name
      self.name = name.downcase.titleize
    end
 
    def set_location
      self.location = LocationService.query(self)
    end
end
```